# Docker on Home PC?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm new to the topic docker and have a general question.

Can I use docker technology on my home pc (OS=Ubuntu 16.04) or do I have to pay for a server to run docker technology?

So far, I have only found articles about docker, that refer to servers.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: have a look at https://www.docker.com/docker-ubuntu. It has Docker CE Support which is free

Answer (score 1):

You can Run Docker on Ubuntu for free . This link https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package
give step by step instruction on how to install docker on Ubuntu .
Docker CE (Free) , Docker EE (Paid)